# MEAN stack: How to store user credentials in mongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, mean-stack

In an online platform built with the MEAN stack, where there is more data attached to the user (e.g.: a game where users have points, coins, medals, presents, and so on):

Is it advised to have a collection with only login info and another with all other player data? So that (still in the same example) when the users' list is fetched to make a ranking screen their passwords are not fetched. (is then the use of the email enough to cross-reference them? Or should both have the ObjectId of the other?)

Or is it safe to have it all in one collection but have the server not to send the encrypted passwords when users list is fetched? Or just filter out the password on the server side?

Are there some industry standards or guidelines for specific cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. it is a good practice to have the authentication part separate from the user data. For example if you look at firebase.

Firebase has authentication separate from the data. The firebase sdk maintains the auth state. And we can have user data in the firestore database.

What I do is that create a user on the database with the documentId the same as the id in Auth. When user logs in. I get the document with the same documentId.